# Могу ли я отправить информацию на сокет через URL?

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, url, tcp

Вот пример кода как реализован Server на Java. Подскажите пожалуйста относительно основного вопроса и реально ли это сделать?

```
package sample.server;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 7777);
        System.out.println("Connected!");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

        System.out.println("Sending string to the ServerSocket");
        String message;
        while (true){
            message = scanner.nextLine();
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(message);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            if(message.equals("disconnect")){
                break;
            }
        }
        dataOutputStream.close();
        System.out.println("Closing socket and terminating program.");
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Объясните, что означает `отправить информацию на сокет через URL`.

Comment: Скорее всего я неправильно выразился. Попробую объяснить на примере, что я хочу. Мне каким то чудным образом через URL нужно передать строку на сервер

Comment: Все еще не понятно, что значит `передать через URL`?

Comment: POST запрос сделать

Comment: Т.е. нужно из java выполнить POST запрос? Как к этому относится код приведенный в вопросе?

Comment: Парни, не мучайте человека. Есть несколько способов передать строку на сервер. Самый простой - это GETom, закодировав её через URL encoding. Чуть посложнее - POST'ом, но тут вже вступают в игру multipart form и прочее, и прочее. Но я подозреваю, что вопрос сформулирован не корректно: мало передать строку на сервер, ведь нужно еще и получить и что то сделать со строкой на сервере. Напишу ка я ответ...

Comment: какой у вас сервер?

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый Евгений,
ваш вопрос немного сбивает с толку.

Смотрите.

Пример, который вы привели - это пример серера, который использует так называемый TCP Socket. Это очень широко известная технология, про котрую есть хорошая [книга](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/translations/bgnet_A4_rus.pdf), которую тут обсуждают в соседнем [вопросе](http://c++%20-%20%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81++%20-%20Stack%20Overflow%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174011/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81).

ТСР - отличный протокол, но он почти не накладывает никаких правил на отпарвляемые и получаемые данные: логика взаимодействия клиента и сервера может быть любой. В частности, я думаю, что если запустить приведенный в примере сервер, то подключиться к нему можно обычным telnet'ом, выполнив что то вроде `telnet localhost 7777`. И тогда после подключения сервер, как я понимаю, будет читать строки до перевода строки а потом посылать их обратно - что то вроде эхо - сервера.

Но делается это из telnet'а, а не из браузера.

Но как только в вопросе возникает слово URL - все мы, старые сетевые волки, делаем стойку, потому что от слова URL пахнет WEB-ом.

Потому, что URL - это universal resource locator, то есть, по русски говоря, "ссылка".

И это слово переводит ответ в область взаимодействия между HTTP серверами и клиентами. Вообще говоря, я немного лукавлю, потому что под понятие URL попадают также ftp - ссылки, но по большей части когда говорят про URL  - говорят про HTTP севера.

А HTTP  - это протокол более выского уровня, чем TCP, или, если говорить другими словами, это протокол, который использует TCP.

Теперь, когда у Вас есть перед глазами эта иерархия, вы можете уточнить свой вопрос.

И уточнение ожидается в таком плане: или "да, я имею в виду сокет, и слово URL здесь лишнее" или "да, я имею в виду именно URL, и слово сокет здесь лишнее".

Иначе - Ваш вопрос становится из технического скорее вопросом на угадывание ответа, потому что непонятно,  что имеется в виду.

Comment: да, только код, вроде, от tcp клиента